# Pyhon3.4 TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, twitter

I am following this guide http://www.mikaelbrunila.fi/2017/03/27/scraping-extracting-mapping-geodata-twitter/ to scrape some tweets using python and geomap them.

After the tweets are stored, i run the second script which includes

```
if tweet['coordinates']:
    user_data["features"]["primary_geo"] = str(tweet['coordinates'][tweet['coordinates'].keys()[1]][1]) + ", " + str(tweet['coordinates'][tweet['coordinates'].keys()[1]][0])
    user_data["features"]["geo_type"] = "Tweet coordinates"
```

and i get the message

> tweet['coordinates'][tweet['coordinates'].keys()[1]][1]) + ", " + str(
>   TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

I understand this was written in python2 while i am now using python3.4 so maybe the str can't be indexed anymore?

What would be the equivalent expression in python3?

**EDIT:**
script:

```
import json

# Tweets are stored in in file "fname". In the file used for this script,
# each tweet was stored on one line
fname = 'test_with_sample.json'
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    # Create dictionary to later be stored as JSON. All data will be included
    # in the list 'data'
    users_with_geodata = {
        "data": []
    }
    all_users = []
    total_tweets = 0
    geo_tweets = 0
    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)

        if tweet['user']['id']:
            total_tweets += 1
            user_id = tweet['user']['id']
            if user_id not in all_users:
                all_users.append(user_id)

                # Give users some data to find them by. User_id listed separately
                # to make iterating this data later easier
                user_data = {
                    "user_id": tweet['user']['id'],
                    "features": {
                        "name": tweet['user']['name'],
                        "id": tweet['user']['id'],
                        "screen_name": tweet['user']['screen_name'],
                        "tweets": 1,
                        "location": tweet['user']['location'],
                    }
                }
                # Iterate through different types of geodata to get the variable primary_geo
                tweet_coords = list(tweet['coordinates'][tweet['coordinates']]).keys()
                tweet_coords2 = list(tweet['coordinates'][tweet['coordinates']]).keys()

                if tweet['coordinates']:
                #    lon = tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][0]
                #   lat = tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][1]
                #    user_data["features"]["lon"] = lon
                #    user_data["features"]["lat"] = lat
                    user_data["features"]["primary_geo"] = str(tweet_coords[1][1]) + ", " + str(tweet_coords2[1][0])
                    user_data["features"]["geo_type"] = "Tweet coordinates"
                if tweet['place']:
                    user_data["features"]["primary_geo"] = tweet['place']['full_name'] + ", " + tweet['place'][
                        'country']
                    user_data["features"]["geo_type"] = "Tweet place"
                else:
                    user_data["features"]["primary_geo"] = tweet['user']['location']
                    user_data["features"]["geo_type"] = "User location"
                # Add only tweets with some geo data to .json. Comment this if you want to include all tweets.
                if user_data["features"]["primary_geo"]:
                    users_with_geodata['data'].append(user_data)
                    geo_tweets += 1

            # If user already listed, increase their tweet count
            elif user_id in all_users:
                for user in users_with_geodata["data"]:
                    if user_id == user["user_id"]:
                        user["features"]["tweets"] += 1
    #except KeyError:
    #    pass

    # Count the total amount of tweets for those users that had geodata
    for user in users_with_geodata["data"]:
        geo_tweets = geo_tweets + user["features"]["tweets"]
    # Get some aggregated numbers on the data
    print
    "The file included " + str(len(all_users)) + " unique users who tweeted with or without geo data"
    print
    "The file included " + str(
        len(users_with_geodata['data'])) + " unique users who tweeted with geo data, including 'location'"
    print
    "The users with geo data tweeted " + str(geo_tweets) + " out of the total " + str(total_tweets) + " of tweets."
# Save data to JSON file
with open('users_geo_sample.json', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(json.dumps(users_with_geodata, indent=4))
```

Comment: `dict.keys()` now return a view, you need `list(dict.keys())` if you want to index them.

Comment: Dictionary keys are not ordered anyway, so getting `.keys()[1]` is most likely broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a data type confusion after all :

```
Tweet['coordinates']
```

returns type dict. The dict contains multiple objects, one of those is a list `coordinates` . So i was able to get the coordinates using :

```
lat = (tweet['coordinates']['coordinates'])[0]
lot = (tweet['coordinates']['coordinates'])[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Dict keys are not containers. They are simply there to view the data.

That's easily fixable:

```
tweet_coords = list(tweet['coordinates'][tweet['coordinates'].keys())
tweet_coords2 = list(tweet['coordinates'][tweet['coordinates'].keys())

if tweet['coordinates']:
user_data["features"]["primary_geo"] = str(tweet_coords[1]][1]) + ", " + str(tweet_coords2[1]][0])
user_data["features"]["geo_type"] = "Tweet coordinates"
```

This way the keys are in a python list container type, not a 'dict keys' type. You should be good from there. Let me know if I can assist further.

Comment: thank you. I get a syntax error in PyCharm : `tweet_coords = list(tweet['coordinates'][tweet['coordinates'].keys())
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Notta prob! Could you copy it in a comment please?

Comment: in my previous comment there is the single message i get at  runtime. The editor shows a ']' is expected at the end of 'tweet_coords = list(tweet['coordinates'][tweet['coordinates'].keys())` .

Comment: I can't be exactly sure here, but would this do the trick?
tweet_coords = list(tweet['coordinates'],tweet['coordinates'].keys()

Comment: i have changed the code to `tweet_coords = list(tweet['coordinates'][tweet['coordinates']]).keys()
                tweet_coords2 = list(tweet['coordinates'][tweet['coordinates']]).keys()

                if tweet['coordinates']:
                    user_data["features"]["primary_geo"] = str(tweet_coords[1][1]) + ", " + str(tweet_coords2[1][0])
                    user_data["features"]["geo_type"] = "Tweet coordinates" `  I get no syntax error now, but it returns :   **tweet_coords = list(tweet['coordinates'][tweet['coordinates']]).keys()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is notsubscriptable**

Comment: OK. What does tweet['coordinates'] return? is a container (i.e a list/array, dictionary?

you are treating tweet['coordinates'] as if it's a list/dictionary (the square brackets immediately follow)

Comment: Actualy wait a second, I missed something. the .keys() call is for dictionaries. You are calling it on a list. Let me know what data type the tweet['coordinates'] return and it'll clear it up

Comment: it is a collection of float e.g `"coordinates":[-97.51087576,35.46500176]`

Comment: Tell you what, post your entire script into your main post, and I'll get it figured out for ya. I know it can be frustrating as hell

Comment: thank you for your help again. I am using the code exactly as found in http://www.mikaelbrunila.fi/2017/03/27/scraping-extracting-mapping-geodata-twitter/. I left out the coordinates part and the script works fine. frustrating indeed !!

Comment: my pleasure. Quick clarification: are you using python2 or 3?

Comment: I am using Python 3.4